# pygame.display.update() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Why this code doesn't work? It says that there is invalid syntax and points to `pygame.display.update()`. I have python 3.5.2 and pygame‑1.9.2rc1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

Ikkuna = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 200), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Erilaisia kuvioita')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

Ikkuna.fill(WHITE)

pygame.draw.circle(Ikkuna, BLACK, (75, 100), 50, 0)
pygame.draw.rect(Ikkuna, RED, (20, 155, 200, 25))
pygame.draw.polygon(Ikkuna, GREEN, ((220, 50),(220,125, (140,125)), 0)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
 sys.exit()
```

Comment: What is the actual error message and stack trace?

Comment: always add full error message (Traceback) in question so we don't have to run code to see it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. This was my first message here :). I will do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed your brackets.

```
pygame.draw.polygon(Ikkuna, GREEN, ((220, 50),(220,125, (140,125)), 0)
```

Should be

```
pygame.draw.polygon(Ikkuna, GREEN, ((220, 50),(220,125), (140,125)), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed also change the file name, which was pygame.py, and then it started to work. Still the "pygame.draw.polygon" doesn't draw anything. Circle and rect are working.

Comment: Just put up a fix.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped, please do accept it.